# "Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader" Error with Materialize Template, OpenCart 3

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I am getting below error in my webstore. What it might be or how can I solve this?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "extension/module/quickorder.twig" (looked into: /home/zulbeaut/ocartdata/storage/modification/catalog/view/theme, /home/zulbeaut/public_html/catalog/view/theme). in /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215 Stack trace: #0 /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(139): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('extension/modul...') #1 /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(312): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('extension/modul...') #2 /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('extension/modul...',bize gelecekmiş NULL) #3 /home/zulbeaut/ocartdata/storage/modification/system/library/template/twig.php(42): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('extension/modul...') #4 /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template.php(51): Template\Twig->render('extension/modul...', '1') #5 /home/zulbeaut/ocartdata/st in /home/zulbeaut/public_html/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 215

Answer (score 1):

First of all - clean **Theme History** in *Design - Theme Editor* for a Default theme.

Although you have to clear **ocmod** cache and **twig** cache.

To clear twig cache in your admin dashboard click on the gear button on top right corner, and then clear the Theme cache.
[image]

To clear **ocmod** cache in admin panel go to *Extensions - Modifications* and click reload button in top right corner. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the plugin, I took a backup after restoring it.
Renewing the modifications was enough for me.